# spfx pnp version issue

Tags: spfx, pnp

I have a spfx. As soon as I import anything from pnp ( @pnp/sp@3.6.0 ), example

```
import { Web } from "@pnp/sp/webs";
```

I get the following error on gulp serve

[image]

it works fine if I have @pnp/sp@2.11.0 but then following code will not work

```
import { spfi, SPFI, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";


export class SPService implements ISPService {

    public static readonly servicekey: ServiceKey<ISPService> = ServiceKey.create<ISPService>('CLog.SPService', SPService);

    private _sp: SPFI;

    constructor(serviceScope: ServiceScope ) {
        serviceScope.whenFinished(() => {
            const pageContext: PageContext = serviceScope.consume(PageContext.serviceKey);
            this._sp = spfi().using(SPFx({ pageContext }));
        });
    }

    public async getListItems(listTitle: string): Promise<any[]> {
        const response = await this._sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Getting pnp version compatible with the SPFx version you are currently using might be time consuming. On top of it, you need to make [sure Node.js, npm, react and TypeScript versions are aligned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility).

To avoid the risk of incompatibility, I recommend [using the PnP SPFx generator](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/). It includes correct versions of the pnp including pnp core and PnP SPFx Controls.

To install the pnp Spfx yeoman generator, run

```
npm install -g @pnp/generator-spfx
```

To run the yeoman generator:

```
yo @pnp/spfx
```

Comment: Thank you Denis